# Converting string with escapes in it to Unicode

Tags: c++, string, unicode, escaping

I want to take a variable, and add it to a string as a command to make a Unicode character. See below for clarification through pseudo-C++:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 50625; i++){

        hexcode = dec_to_hex(i+32);     //this already works & returns a hex string
        unicode_var = U"\u$(hexcode)";     //inserts hexcode into the command for a Unicode char (I used PHPish syntax to help convey this) 
    }
```

What do I do to "insert" the variable as a string and get it interpreted as part of a command?
Forgive me if this is a stupidly simple question; C++ is still mysterious to me.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it seems you are working too hard. I think you are looking for `wchar_t unicode_var = static_cast<wchar_t>(i+32);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Printing out `unicode_var` just prints `i+32`, not its Unicode equivalent. Am I missing something?

Comment: How exactly are you printing? Are you using `cout`, by any chance (if so, change it to `wcout`)?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks! `wcout` did the trick!